# How to prevent a "fatal" error output while aliasing a git command

Tags: git, shell, zsh

How can I prevent the outputting of the fatal error message? I intend on aliasing a few git commands without STDOUT nor STDERR. After appending `2>&1 >/dev/null` I continue to get fatal error messages when aliasing the commands.

[image]

Some of the commands are aliased by z-shell's (zsh) git plugin. As part of my *.zshrc* file I source an *aliases.zsh* file where I unalias then reapply the alias with a new command.

> From aliases.zsh

```sh
# -- Git related -------------------------------------------------- 
unalias grmci 2>&1 >/dev/null 
alias grmci 2>&1 >/dev/null || alias grmci="git rm --cached `git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore`" 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

Comment: I guess I could read the source code of the zsh plugin and see how they are doing it however, that wouldn't tell me why my approach doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, are you sure you don't want `git ls-files --others`?

Comment: The very short of "why your approach doesn't work" is that when you use double quotes, you're running `git ls-files` *while defining your alias*, instead of deferring it until when the alias is run. Using functions instead avoids the whole problem; they no longer need the text of code to be run, so one doesn't need to worry about how to escape that code into a string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed, after reading the man-page I do want to use `--others` as it would account for my global ignore file. Thanks for making the extra effort in answering the question.

Comment: (BTW, I generally advise against anything that redirects stderr to /dev/null unconditionally; sure, it eliminates the errors you're trying to hide, but it also eliminates unexpected errors as well. Safer to do something like `2> >(grep -Ev 'error you want to hide|other error you want to hide' >&2)` to hide only expected errors and leave unexpected ones visible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, use a function instead. Assuming you have GNU rather than BSD `xargs`:

```
# this runs not just on zsh, but also on ksh/bash/etc with GNU xargs.
# (would be POSIX-compliant but for $'\n' syntax for literal newlines)
grmci() {
  {
    git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore |
      xargs --no-run-if-empty -d $'\n' \
      git rm --cached
  } >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

...or, relying on the shell to do more of the work and not depending on xargs at all:

```
# this is zsh-only code; 1-indexed arrays and `(@f)...` parameterization are zsh-isms
grmci() {
  {
    array_of_lines=("${(@f)$(git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore)}")
    { (( ${#array_of_lines[@]} )) && [[ ${array_of_lines[1]} != '' ]]; } || 
return 0
    git rm --cached -- "${array_of_lines[@]}"
  } >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

Note that in neither case do we use `$(git ls-files ...)` directly as an argument to `git rm --cached`; doing this misbehaves when files contain whitespace, glob characters, etc. in their names. (The code we have now doesn't tolerate filenames with literal newlines, but neither does `git`).

Answer (score 0):

BSD compliant solution using information shared by @CharlesDuffy.

The following functions check if an alias exists, removing it if so. Then the `grmci` function can be used to remove ignored files.

```c
removeAlias () {
  CMDTYPE=$(type "$1") 
  case $CMDTYPE in
    *"alias"*)
      unalias $1 2> >(grep -Ev 'no such hash table element' >&2)
    ;;
    *"function"*)
      echo -e "\u001b[34mError: alias is a function\u001b[0m"
    ;;
    *"not found"*)
    ;;
    *)
      echo -e "Error: unknown command type for $1 return message is '$CMDTYPE'"
    ;;
  esac
}

# -- Git related----------------------------- 
removeAlias grmci
grmci () {
  git ls-files --others |
    xargs -n1 git rm --cached
}
```